# Internal spark-submit logs

Tags: apache-spark

I have a Apache Spark 1.6.3 application that suddenly crashes without exception or stack trace (logging is set to debug level). The console output does not show any error and I have therefore no idea where to start searching for the bug. I start the application using

```
spark-submit --master "local[4]" --driver-memory 10g --deploy-mode client --class ... app.jar
```

Is there a way to get to Spark internal logs and where would they be stored? Or what other way do I have to get to know where the bug comes from?

Comment: Have you seen logs from Spark UI?

Comment: Executor logs should contain some information.

Comment: Since not only the application crashes but also Spark, I do not see the UI. Where would the executor logs be?